# Prometheus Flask exporter with __main__

Tags: python, flask, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to use [Prometheus Flask exporter](https://pypi.org/project/prometheus-flask-exporter/) with `__main__`.

This works fine by running `env FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --port=80 --host='0.0.0.0'`:

```
from flask import Flask
from prometheus_flask_exporter import PrometheusMetrics

app = Flask(__name__)
metrics = PrometheusMetrics(app)

app.debug = True

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "hello world"
```

But I want to use my app in `__main__`, running `python app.py`.

```
from flask import Flask
from prometheus_flask_exporter import PrometheusMetrics

app = Flask(__name__)
metrics = PrometheusMetrics(app=None, path='/metrics')

app.debug = True

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    metrics.init_app(app)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Here I get 400 on `/metrics`.

I got no clue how to init metrics correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help on [gitlab from maintainer rycus86](https://github.com/rycus86/prometheus_flask_exporter/issues/40)

You have to set env [DEBUG_METRICS](https://github.com/rycus86/prometheus_flask_exporter/blob/master/README.md#debug-mode) on any value (true/false).
It just must not be empty.

```
export DEBUG_METRICS=false
```